# How to allow http links in an iframe in a .NET Core 6 Blazor Hybrid app

Tags: .net, maui

I am trying to have an IFrame with src="http://ip-address"

but I get the error: `Mixed Content: The page at 'https://0.0.0.0/sungrow' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://10.0.0.150:80/'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

Thanks in advance!

Best regards Max

Comment: That's not a Blazor issue.  It's a security issue.

Comment: Is there a way I can avoid the issue and go around the security?

Comment: Make sure your secondary resources is also secure.

Comment: (don’t call http from https) - disallowed in modern browsers

Comment: I have now changed to https, but the certificate is untrusted, this is my new error I get this error in my console The Content Security Policy directive 'frame-ancestors' is ignored when delivered via a <meta> element.
blazor.webview.js:1 
        
       The Content Security Policy directive 'frame-ancestors' is ignored when delivered via a <meta> element.